# A 14 month often old waking up in terror for weeks

Tags: toddler, night-time, nightwaking

A 14 month old girl wakes up about 3 a.m. sometimes screaming bloody murder or just all of a sudden sitting up in bed and watching the ceiling like she sees something. It's spooky. Cats do that sometimes. She is such a lovely baby and a happy baby. This has been going on for a couple of weeks. One time she was screaming eyes wide open and holding her arms straight up. It freaks me out.  Is this normal?

Comment: Sounds like night terrors to me, that's very common at that age.

Comment: Hello and welcome Irene.  Are you looking to find out what to do about the situation or are you looking for an explanation as to the cause or something else?  Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 4):

Given your description, it is not paranormal, it is **NORMAL** :)

These are called night terrors, which children in that age have, and they are perfectly normal. You may still want to check this out with your pediatrician, since the normal age for night terrors to develop is 3 years old+ (though children as young as 6 mos. can also have them).

If you want to understand more about night terrors, google it. Here are some samples I found:

http://voices.yahoo.com/what-know-infant-toddler-night-4836284.html

http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/night-terrors

http://www.babycenter.com/404_why-is-my-toddler-suddenly-waking-up-hysterical-at-night_1292621.bc

Comment: What causes night terrors at 14 months. They are too young to dream aren't they.

Comment: they are not really dreams, dreams (and nightmares) happen during REM sleep. Night-terrors happen during transition from REM to NON-REM sleep. Possibly some form of scare during (or as a result of) the transition. According to experts, dreams, at least with a defined plot-line begin at 4-6 years of age. See: http://www.mnn.com/family/babies-pregnancy/stories/do-babies-dream